# WiX display Maintenance dialog when Repair is started from ARP

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3

Is there some way a UI can be enabled when Repair is started from ARP? Somehow Change runs with full UI and Repair only with minimum UI. I'm using WiX 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [ARPNOREPAIR Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to disable to repair button and force the user to select Change.  From there they could do a Change, Repair or Remove.   MSI and ARP works together to provide a Basic UI experience for Repair and Remove without any option to change it other then what I just mentioned.